Can I improve performance of this deletion with `LEFT JOIN`, `IS NULL` and `LIMIT`?
I'm running a deletion on a data set, currently shy of 3.5 million entries, and limiting each iteration to 2500 entries at once.
The reason for the limit is mostly to not block transactions too long in the database, but also not the worker containers running the actual jobs, which re-enqueues itself until all data is gone.
For this, I've two queries.
First: check if actual data to delete exists
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM "table_groups"
                       LEFT JOIN "table_entries" ON "table_entries"."table_groups_group_id" = "table_groups"."id"
              WHERE "table_groups"."wrkspc_id" = 987654321
                  AND
                    "table_entries"."id" IS NULL
                    ) AS "exists";

-> https://explain.depesz.com/s/9JDt
Second: perform the actual deletion
DELETE FROM table_groups
WHERE table_groups.id IN (
  SELECT table_groups.id
  FROM table_groups
    LEFT JOIN table_entries
      ON table_groups.id = table_entries.table_groups_group_id
  WHERE
        -- table_groups_wrkspc_id_idx
        table_groups.wrkspc_id = 987654321 AND
        table_entries.id IS NULL
  LIMIT 2500
);

-> https://explain.depesz.com/s/v6Qs
One "deletion iteration" (i.e. exists check + actual deletion, then the job starts over), takes about 2-3 mins.
The concept of those queries is that:

there's a table table_groups which references entries from table_entries, i.e. groups them
if a table_groups entry is not references from any table_entries entry, it can be deleted (millions of entries in total)

The idea is to have the LEFT JOIN and check on table_entries.id IS NULL to figure out the ones in table_groups not being referenced.
The query plans include the timings and I've all the indices I could think off.
Table structures
                                      Table "public.table_groups"
  Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                      Default
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 id        | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('table_groups_id_seq'::regclass)
 wrkspc_id | bigint                   |           | not null |
 created   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 modified  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "table_groups_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "table_groups_wrkspc_id_idx" btree (wrkspc_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_groups_wrkspc_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (wrkspc_id) REFERENCES workspaces(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "table_entries" CONSTRAINT "table_entries_table_groups_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (table_groups_group_id) REFERENCES table_groups(id)


                                              Table "public.table_entries"
          Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 id                       | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('table_entries_id_seq'::regclass)
 chn_id                   | bigint                   |           |          |
 table_groups_group_id    | bigint                   |           |          |
Indexes:
    "table_entries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "table_entries_chn_id_idx" btree (chn_id)
    "table_entries_table_groups_group_id_idx" btree (table_groups_group_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_entries_chn_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (chn_id) REFERENCES chn(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "table_entries_table_groups_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (table_groups_group_id) REFERENCES table_groups(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "chn" CONSTRAINT "chn_table_entries_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (chn_id) REFERENCES table_entries(id) ON DELETE SET NULL

I'm not sure if it can be done faster, surely there's an overhead because every batch of 2k5 iteration performs an exists, which takes time, and then the actual deletion, again taking time. But such a deletion must not block for too long and if I would delete them with a single statement, it could lead to other issues in the system due to locks, so for quite some time the iterative approach is used and overall works great.
In the plans I provided it's using "Seq Scan" and I know what this means, planner decided to not use the indices. Interestingly, when I extract the SELECT block within the DELETE, it actually uses "Parallel Seq Scan" but overall also isn't much faster anyway.
[In case it's useful: this is on AWS Aurora Postgres, using some 16.x version]
Thanks

The solution was provided by @Akina

and (if possible) add the index table_groups (wrkspc_id, id)

Adding that index immediately solved the performance problems, thank you!
